# Griffon 1.2 - mail plugin does not look at mailhost param

Tags: griffon

I installed Griffon 1.2 and the mail plugin.

`griffon install-plugin mail`

I created a test:

```
 sendMail(mailhost: '192.168.0.19', 
                to: 'me@home.com', 
                from: 'me@home.com', 
                subject: 'Test Mail', 
                text:'''
            Hello
            World''')
```

But it does not  use the mailhost param. It tries to use localhost:

`javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25`

I verified the SMTP server via telnet commands and that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 70 from https://github.com/griffon/griffon-mail-plugin/blob/master/src/main/griffon/plugins/mail/MailSender.groovy shows that `mailhost` is taken into account, at least when it comes to setting properties.

However this sounds more of a bug report than an actual question. If so I'd recommend you to post the issue to the Griffon user list. If it's found to be a bug then a report should be made to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/griffon